# Where can I find Blender tutorials?

Tags: blender

Where are some blender tutorials, (preferably 2.63)

I used blender back in the old days, when they used the old GUI.
and since then i havened used it. I want to learn it again, but the GUI change makes it difficult,

I like it but still. I would love some tutorials not only for the new GUI.
but a full blender tutorial is welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [BlenderCookie](http://cgcookie.com/blender/)
- [The interface explained](http://www.blendtuts.com/2010/06/blender-25-interface.html)
- [Official Blender website](http://www.blender.org/education-help/tutorials/)
- [Blendernation](http://www.blendernation.com/category/education/tutorials/)

All found on the first page of a Google search...

Comment: Thanks, i usually search on youtube but not all are for 2.63 didn't know if i would get confused trying to find a button that isn't there. So i thought I ask it here for some help. Thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Blender homepage has bunch of [original tutorials](http://www.blender.org/education-help/tutorials/).
And AFAIK, are based on new GUI (most of tutorials are based on 2.5 and greater), so users will not get confused.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend:
http://www.blenderguru.com/

it's not for novices but you can find a lot of interesting staff.

Also you can find those tutorials on youtube.com under Andrew Price chanel (blenderguru himself)